# How to ignore bot specific messages using discordjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord.js

Is there a way to ignore specific bot messages?

I'm trying with this.

`if (message.author.bot) return;`

But this is ignoring all the bot messages and I just want to ignore specifics messages, not all of them.

Comment: By putting some conditions

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
//noReply should contain unanswered messages    
const noReply = [ 'messages noReply','noReply exp','noReply hello','nop noReply','xxx','one a one','lazy' ];
const mab = message.content;
if (noReply.some(msgs => msgs == mab)) return;
```

or use filter, switch

Comment: How does this work? You never used `message.content` so I am a bit confused right here.

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong. in message.author.bot the correct would be message.content

Answer (score 1):

```
const blacklist = ['test', 'hello', 'world']

if(blacklist.includes(message.content)) return
```

The above code only ignores if the message is exactly typed as it is in the list (case-sensitive). If you want it to not be case sensitive, change `message.content` to `message.content.toLowerCase()` and make sure your list only contains the lowercase versions.

If you want to check each word, you can simply use a loop through each word.

```
const blacklist = ['test', 'hello', 'world']

const words = message.content.split(' ')
words.forEach(word => {
    if(blacklist.contains(word)) return
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Start each blacklisted message with a certain phrase, or keep a list of them in the `blacklist` array

```js
// Inside of message event
const blacklist = ['noreply', 'dnr']; // These are case sensitive
if (message.author.bot) {             // and may contain spaces

  // Otherwise anyone could start their message with "noreply" and be ignored
  if (blacklist.some(phrase => message.content.startsWith(phrase))) return;
  // .... continue with rest of code
}
```

NOTE: Don't use just `blacklist.some(message.content.startsWith)` because it will skip some words based on the index of the phrase in `blacklist`

[Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

[String.prototype.startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)